# Encountered error Syntax error in JOIN operation

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, adodb

**OBJECTIVE:** trying to extract data using union all with join.

**CODE:**

```
MYSQL = "SELECT trans_id, item_id, SUM(OrigQty) AS NewOrigQty, SUM(TempQty) AS NewTempQty, " & _
"itm_name, itm_category, itm_details, itm_um, itm_cost " & _
"FROM (" & _
"SELECT T1.trans_id, T1.item_id, T1.itm_qty AS OrigQty, 0 AS TempQty, " & _
"T3.itm_name, T3.itm_category, T3.itm_details, T3.itm_um, T3.itm_cost FROM INVENTORY AS T1 " & _
"LEFT JOIN ITEM AS T3 ON T1.item_id = T3.itm_id " & _
"WHERE T1.trans_id = '" & NewSearchList.lvSearchWindow.SelectedItem.Text & "' " & _
"AND T1.itm_movement = 'TRANSFER IN' AND T1.inv_temporig_status = 'ORIGINAL' " & _
"UNION ALL " & _
"SELECT T2.trans_id, T2.item_id, 0 AS OrigQty, T2.itm_qty AS TempQty, " & _
"t4.itm_name, t4.itm_category, t4.itm_details, t4.itm_um, t4.itm_cost FROM INVENTORY AS T2 " & _
"LEFT JOIN ITEM AS t4 ON T1.item_id = T4.itm_id " & _
"WHERE T2.trans_id = '" & NewSearchList.lvSearchWindow.SelectedItem.Text & "' " & _
"AND T2.itm_movement = 'TRANSFER IN' AND T2.inv_temporig_status = 'TEMPORARY' " & _
") x " & _
"GROUP BY trans_id, item_id, itm_name, itm_category, itm_details, itm_um, itm_cost"

Set rsInventory = dbInventory.Execute(MYSQL)
```

**ERROR:** Syntax error in JOIN operation

Comment: Have you tried pasting the result string into a query? Sometimes you can get more information that way. And is `trans_id` really a string field?

Comment: hi thank you for your reply. yes i did and your are right trans_id is a string field. by the way i'm using access as my database

Comment: Did you test each SELECT in query object before building UNION? AFAIK, a recordset is not set with Execute. Execute is for action SQL (DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE). `Set rsInventory = dbInventory.OpenRecordset(MYSQL)`.

Comment: thanks @June7 i did what you said. i test eat select and found out after union all the error occurs. i  dont know whats the cause. so what i did is i replicate my first select and it works. again thanks. :)